# Trying to delete index.html document but stays when I refresh the page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm very new to programming and am having some issues with HTML/CSS. I have this index.html file that I made which is composed of a basic template and copied code navbar example from off of twitter bootstrap. I am launching this page from off of my chrome browser.

The issue I'm running into is that no matter how much content I delete off of this index.html document and then hit "CTRL+S", when I refresh the page, the content on the webpage still appears the same. It's gotten to the point where I only have !DOCTYPE html and html but the content still reloads/loads/doesn't change. Is it possible that the page is still around on local storage? I tried deleting my browser cache to no avail.

Please let me know if there is anything I can do to configure it so I can delete a portion of content at one time (that way I can sort of learn what each component, class, id does).

Comment: Most likely the file you are viewing in your browser is not the file you are making changes to.

Answer (score 0):

It may be saved to your cache. Some website builders have a "Save To Cache" autosave, and you need to clear this, they should provide a button. If you're doing it yourself simply clear your cache in your Chrome Browser by going to the three vertical dots on the top right of your page -> Down to Settings -> Down to Advanced (Requires A Click) -> Down to Clear Browsing Data -> Select only Cached Images and Files -> Select a Day or Week to Be Safe. And when you reload your webpage now, it should be resolved.

Comment: As the person says above. Clear you cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think my issue was that I had to close out of the index.html file for the changes to take effect, but the day/week clear cache may have also helped with the problem.